# Adding Component's State to a String in React

Tags: string, reactjs, components

I have a component with the following states:

```
class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      var1: "Dog",
      var2: "Cat",
      var3: [20, 40],
      currentFilter:"None"
    };
      this.updateFilter = this.updateFilter.bind(this);
  }
```

In the update filter function, I want to incorporate all the state properties, but the following syntax does not work:

```
updateFilter(){
  var newSearch= "Searching" {this.state.var1} + {this.state.var2}
  this.setState({
    currentFilter: newSearch
  });
}
```

Is there a way to incorporate the properties of state into the string variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the curly braces unless you're writing JSX. Since your `updateFilter()` function is just a normal Javascript function, you can write it as:

```js
updateFilter() {
  var newSearch = "Searching" + this.state.var1 + this.state.var2;
  this.setState({
    currentFilter: newSearch
  });
}
```

Though, FYI, what you'll get for `newSearch` will be an incoherent `"SearchingDogCat"` so you may want to rethink your concatenation.

Comment: Thanks! And the example I used is just a very simplified bare bones version of my app, but point taken.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
updateFilter() {
  var newSearch = `Searching ${this.state.var1} ${this.state.var2} `;
  this.setState({
    currentFilter: newSearch
  });
}
```

Note those aren't single quotes. They are `